# How do I present a modal UINavigation view over my tab bar iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Here is the code I am calling to pop a navigation controller over my entire tab bar app:

```
LoginViewController *logController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
EditNavController *navController = [[EditNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:logController];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```

and I am getting the following warning in my log:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <EditNavController: 0xa95b980> on <MyTabController: 0x1152fd60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The code works, but I want to do it the correct way so this warning doesn't appear.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if MyTabController is a tabbarcontroller, you should use

```
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

remember that presentModalViewController:animated: is [deprecated since iOS6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html). I think the problem is you are trying to present the viewController in Navigation Controller of the tabbar, wich is not in the view hierarchy (because it's not shown). Instead, you should present the modal view controller in the Tab Bar controller (wich IS in the view hierarchy).
I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Now I am getting this... Warning: Attempt to present <EditNavController: 0xadbe330> on <MyTabController: 0xafb6400> while a presentation is in progress! - Any ideas? Maybe open another question here on StackOverflow?

Comment: probably you are presenting the view controller twice, Can you provide us with some more code? May be debugging only with breakpoints to see how many times this code is being called could help!

Comment: Yes, it was getting called twice. Fixed. Thanks! Now the warnings are all gone!

Comment: perfect! can you mark this answer as your solution? just to earn some points =)!